# the ios designer mac agent is not available

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.ios

Hi am using visual studio 2015 community to create ios app.I am getting this error all time like the ios designer  mac  agent is not available.I am using win-7 64-bit os.[image]

Comment: i don't think u can ever create ios apps on any other platform than mac. they don't even allow you to download xcode. neither allow ios emulation

Comment: now we can create ios app using xamarin which support .Net c#. and you can run on mac os.

Comment: I have the same problem. Don't know how to do.

Comment: @Jitendrasingh ; is there any solution you find for your problem ?

Answer (score 4):

You have to have a Mac paired with your Windows OS in order to utilize the iOS Designer.

#### Xamarin.iOS Requirements:

- Windows 7 or higher.
- Visual Studio 2012 Professional or higher.
- Xamarin for Visual Studio.
- A Mac running OS X Yosemite (10.10) or higher (although we recommend the latest stable version).
- Xamarin iOS SDK.
- Apple’s Xcode(7+) IDE and iOS SDK (we recommend the latest version from the App Store).

The Windows computer must be able to reach the Mac via the network.

> Xamarin.iOS for Visual Studio accomplishes an amazing feat: it lets you create, build, and debug iOS applications on a Windows computer using the Visual Studio IDE. It cannot do this alone – iOS applications cannot be created without Apple’s compiler, and they cannot be deployed without Apple’s certificates and code-signing tools. This means that your Xamarin.iOS for Visual Studio installation requires a connection to a networked Mac OS X computer in order to perform these tasks. Once configured, Xamarin’s tools will make the process as seamless as possible.

Ref: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/windows/#System_Requirement

Comment: Thanks sushiHangover, yes I have all setup required, but i am getting this problem some time  not all time.

Comment: @Jitendrasingh Ah, ok, that was not clear in your question. Are you connecting to your Mac via Wifi? Or physical network cable? If Wifi, try using a physical cable. When the error occurs, can you `ping` your Mac, can you get an manually created SSH connection (port 22) to it from your Windows machine?

Comment: ya i am connected with network cable. and i am able to ping that machine.

Comment: A couple things to try: Ensure the same version of Xamarin is installed on both Windows and the Mac host. There are some firewall rules to update, and some permissions to grant - Xamarin's article should cover that. Make sure your WiFi connection isn't spotty, as Sushi recommended. Also, make sure to launch XCode - it may be waiting for you to agree to something, especially after any updates!

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me perhaps it might work for you

**Delete** the **Xamarin** folder in your **%localappdata%\Local\Temp**

If this fails reinstall/update mono on Mac